# Fragment goes up when using fragment transaction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have two fragments: ListFragment and BlankFragment. I'm using supportFragmentManager for navigation between these fragments, but after adding BlankFragment in beginTransaction it goes up, so first lines of textView are not visible.

This is a transaction:

```kotlin
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(
                    R.id.fragmentContainerView,
                    BlankFragment()).
                addToBackStack("").commit()
```

this is how fragment must look like:
[expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rom4Y.jpg)

but this is how it actually looks like:
[reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANSc1.jpg)